# gitolite3 v3.5.2-g2515992 mirroring issue

Tags: gitolite, mirroring

Hi I was trying to setup mirroring in gitolite3 version 3.5.2.

I had followed steps as specified in this link http://gitolite.com/gitolite/mirroring/

but when ran this command on the master server 
`gitolite mirror push LIP-SLAVE gitolite-admin`

I am getting this below msg
FATAL: HOSTNAME not set

I had set HOSTNAME in .gitolite.rc file in gitolite admin home dir. but gitolite is not picking it up

Does any one know how to set HOSTNAME is gitolite v3.5.2

Thanks in advance